# Sending Whole Json to kafka with avro serialization?

Tags: java, json, data-structures, apache-kafka, avro

I have a json file that i want to sent it's contents to a Kafka consumer. The kafka uses Avro and a Schema that adheres to the Json i want to send .So is there a way to read the json and then send the whole contents of it through kafka without the need to first parse the json and then send everything separately with keys and values?

Thanks.

Comment: Using Avro, you can define the structure of your data. Instead of sending data in JSON; I would recommend to use Avro format. Checkou thttps://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/schema_registry_tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the Schema Registry, sure, you can remove whitespace from the file, then read it as stdin

```
kafka-avro-console-consumer  ... < $(cat file.json)
```

Otherwise, you would need to write your own producer to be able to plugin the Avro serializer

Comment: I have a producer, is there a way to send the whole this from there ?

Comment: I mean if i try to send the json it is send as a string.

Comment: Sounds like you are using the wrong `value.serial8zer`